# parsing json localhost android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to connect my android application with local host.I have done r and d,and implemented lots of codes.But didnot get success.Here is my  code for establishing connection.Its showing in ddms  connection to localhost refused

http://pastebin.com/wVmzdQvA

when i run the url on browser its opening.Dont know where actually the problem is

If anyone can guide me

Regards
Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simple when you think about it.

`localhost` on your laptop, and `localhost` on your android phone are not the same.

You are telling your phone to connect to `phpmyadmin` running on the phone... not on your laptop.

You need to have an external ip address for your laptop, and connect to this.

Try http://www.whatismyip.com or `ifconfig` to find out an ip address your phone can use to connect.

Lets say that within your local network you have the ip `192.168.1.14`, then you should be able to connect by replacing `127.0.0.1` with `192.168.1.14`.

Comment: @mathew,,i have changed the url by ip address,,still same problem,,persists,,,,,do u have skype

Comment: do you get the same error, if its a different error, I suggest you post it as a new question, along with the output from `logcat`. Hopefully will give us a good idea.

Comment: @mathew its same error ....i am posting my logcat file,,,http://pastebin.com/n8Dgy5AY

Comment: `Connection to http://127.0.0.1 refused` means you are trying to connect to the localhost on the loopback address.

Comment: @user988771 I don't think you've changed your code. The error still says "127.0.0.1". If you are on the same network try to find your local ip address (mine is 192.168.1.123) but really you should be running your server externally. I suggest you try to setup a VPS somewhere with a domain name. Thereby its less confusing. `someserver.example.com`